# How to delete a selected row in a html table by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm trying to delete a selected row in a table using jQuery.

This is my html markup:

```
<table id="resultTable">
 <tr id="first">
  <td>c1</td>      
  <td>c2</td>      
 </tr>
 <tr id="second">
  <td>c3</td>      
  <td>c4</td>      
  </tr>    
</table>
<button id="del">Clear</button>
```

This is the script I'm using..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {   
     var tid="";   

     $('#resultTable tr').click(function (event) {
        tid=$(this).attr('id');
          alert(tid); //trying to alert id of the clicked row   
     });

     $("#del").click(function(){
     alert("removing "+ tid);
            $(tid).remove();    
     });
 });
</script>
```

I'm declaring a global variable "tid" to obtain "rowId" and using the same variable in both click() function. But I'm unable to delete the corresponding row, please help me

Comment: you miss '#' in '$(tid)'

Comment: Check my answer to see a generalized practice for delete selected item.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39718072/6608101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate `#` to make it valid `ID` selector, without `#`, jQuery will look for `<first>/<second>` elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tid = "";
  $('#resultTable tr').click(function(event) {
    tid = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  $("#del").click(function() {
    console.log(tid);
    if ($('#' + tid).length) {
      $('#' + tid).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultTable">
  <tr id="first">
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="second">
    <td>c3</td>
    <td>c4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="del">Clear</button>
```

Comment: @alokshreevathsa – Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Comment: This is removing ALL rows in my case; not just the row referenced by the selector. Unfortunately, this isn't reflected on the fiddle which does nothing when I click the delete button (https://jsfiddle.net/urv1znLj/)

Answer (score 0):

You missed `#` with element id

```
     $("#del").click(function(){
            alert("removing "+ tid);
            $('#' + tid).remove();    // you need to add #
     });
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xab10nq/)

You can learn more on remove in jquery from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you don't require any clear button over there.

As you said, you want to delete a selected row,
Try to use `confirm` box for user inputs to delete a particular element.

If you would like use global delete for multiple selected elements, you can use check-box for each row and push them into a single variable, once user clicks on clear / delete button delete all selected rows. That will be a good practice.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tid = "";
  $('#resultTable tr').click(function(event) {
    tid = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(tid);
    if(confirm("Are you sure, you want to delete : "+tid))
    {
      $('#'+tid).remove();  
    }  
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tid = "";
  $('#resultTable tr').click(function(event) {
    tid = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(tid);
    if(confirm("Are you sure, you want to delete : "+tid))
    {
      $('#'+tid).remove();  
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultTable">
  <tr id="first">
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="second">
    <td>c3</td>
    <td>c4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this as well

**Html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table id="resultTable">
   <tr id="first">
     <td>c1</td>
     <td>c2</td>
    </tr>
   <tr id="second">
     <td>c3</td>
     <td>c4</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <button id="del">Clear</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tid = "";
   $('#resultTable tr').on('click',function () {
    tid = '#'+ $(this).attr('id');
   });
   $("#del").click(function() { 
    if ($(tid).length > 0) {
    $(tid).remove();
     }
   });
});
```

check code on [JsFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/61/)